# Azure Devops creating a new pull requests points to an invalid branch

Tags: azure-devops

i am using Azure Devops and have an issue while creating a new pull request. Every pull request that i create, points to a very old release branch which leads to many unnecessary calls to find the delta between both branches (linked work items and file diff). I tried many things, but i am not able to let it point back to develop.

What black magic is needed to achieve this?

I tried to open the develop branch on the files page.
I tried to open the develop branch through the branchs page.

Comment: and just in this moment i found the solution (facepalm) ... i somehow changed the compare branch in the branches overview

Comment: Cool.   I was going to suggest you use the CLI: 1) Identify your repo's branch(es) `az repos ref list...`, 2) Create a PR for the specific branch you wanted `az repos pr create...`.  SUGGESTION: Post an "answer", then "accept" it. Clarify exactly how you were making the pull request, how you "mixed up" the branch, and how you ultimately resolved the problem.